# Optimal way to move a file

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

So in order to move a file in Drive API, can it be done by using the patch method with options in the array(removeParents, addParents) or by imodyfing it with the parents delete()/insert() methods? Any idea on how does it work?

Comment: Have you tried patching the parent id?

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Still not sure if removeParent() or addParent() would be better though...